# Using gridster in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, gridster

I'm trying to use gridster (jQuery plugin) in my ASP.Net MVC application with no success.
I have installed the gridster Nuget package. Added both CSS and JS in bundles. My test view includes the tutorial code.

**BundleConfig.cs:**

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/gridster").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery.gridster.js"));

bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/gridstercss").Include(
                  "~/Content/jquery.gridster.css"));
```

**Text.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Test";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutSimple.cshtml";
}

<h2>Test</h2>

<div class="gridster">
    <ul>
        <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">1</li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">2</li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">3</li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">4</li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="2">5</li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">6</li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="4" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1">7</li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="4" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">8</li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">9</li>
        <li data-row="3" data-col="5" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">10</li>

        <li data-row="1" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">11</li>
        <li data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2">12</li>
    </ul>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/gridster")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/gridstercss")

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { //DOM Ready

        $(".gridster ul").gridster({
            widget_margins: [10, 10],
            widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140]
        });

    });
</script>
```

The error I get when I load the page is:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).gridster is not a function

What am I doing wrong? Why is the documentation on Nuget packages so sparse?